# Magento sold more products than in inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, database, inventory, quantity, cataloginventory

My client had a big traffic on server for 1 day. They added one product (ID X) with quantity = 10000. After few hours they sold about 15000 items of this product - I can say because of simple query:

```
SELECT SUM(sales_flat_order_item.qty_ordered) FROM sales_flat_order_item INNER JOIN sales_flat_order ON sales_flat_order_item.order_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id WHERE sales_flat_order.created_at >= 'XXXX-XX-XX 08:00:02' AND sales_flat_order.created_at <= 'XXXX-XX-XX 13:00:00' WHERE sales_flat_order_item.product_id = X
```

So how it's possible that Magento sold so many items? I'm sure that they've started from 8:00 AM with exactly 10000 items.

I've found MySQL log with all queries from that day. There are many weird entries. Starting from 8:00 AM. They started with 10000 items like I wrote before. I can see it from that query:

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `product_id` = 'X', `stock_id` = '1', `qty` = '10000', `min_qty` = '0', `use_config_min_qty` = '1', `is_qty_decimal` = '0', `backorders` = '0', `use_config_backorders` = '1', `min_sale_qty` = '1', `use_config_min_sale_qty` = '1', `max_sale_qty` = '10', `use_config_max_sale_qty` = '0', `is_in_stock` = '1', `low_stock_date` = 'XXXX-XX-XX 08:00:02', `notify_stock_qty` = NULL, `use_config_notify_stock_qty` = '1', `manage_stock` = '0', `use_config_manage_stock` = '1', `stock_status_changed_auto` = '0', `use_config_qty_increments` = '1', `qty_increments` = '0', `use_config_enable_qty_inc` = '1', `enable_qty_increments` = '0', `is_decimal_divided` = '0' WHERE (item_id='X')
```

After this it's getting really weird. They set product as visible and they started to sell it. Here are first queries for first orders (shown in execute order):

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-2 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
```

So there were two orders, so Magento should substract 3 items, but next query is:

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `product_id` = 'X', `stock_id` = '1', `qty` = '9998', `min_qty` = '0', `use_config_min_qty` = '1', `is_qty_decimal` = '0', `backorders` = '0', `use_config_backorders` = '1', `min_sale_qty` = '1', `use_config_min_sale_qty` = '1', `max_sale_qty` = '10', `use_config_max_sale_qty` = '0', `is_in_stock` = '1', `low_stock_date` = 'XXXX-XX-XX 08:03:49', `notify_stock_qty` = NULL, `use_config_notify_stock_qty` = '1', `manage_stock` = '0', `use_config_manage_stock` = '1', `stock_status_changed_auto` = '0', `use_config_qty_increments` = '1', `qty_increments` = '0', `use_config_enable_qty_inc` = '1', `enable_qty_increments` = '0', `is_decimal_divided` = '0' WHERE (item_id='X')
```

There are many entries like this. I don't understand why Magento substracted items before and after this (just second later) tries to set specific quantity.

I've checked custom modules - there are no customisations for orders/quantity/inventory - I'm sure. We use 1.9.0.1 CE.

Please, someone have any idea what could happen?

If someone want to see whole log for "cataloginventory_stock_item" table. Here are some more queries shown in execute order:

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-2 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `product_id` = 'X', `stock_id` = '1', `qty` = '9998', `min_qty` = '0', `use_config_min_qty` = '1', `is_qty_decimal` = '0', `backorders` = '0', `use_config_backorders` = '1', `min_sale_qty` = '1', `use_config_min_sale_qty` = '1', `max_sale_qty` = '10', `use_config_max_sale_qty` = '0', `is_in_stock` = '1', `low_stock_date` = 'XXXX-XX-XX 08:03:49', `notify_stock_qty` = NULL, `use_config_notify_stock_qty` = '1', `manage_stock` = '0', `use_config_manage_stock` = '1', `stock_status_changed_auto` = '0', `use_config_qty_increments` = '1', `qty_increments` = '0', `use_config_enable_qty_inc` = '1', `enable_qty_increments` = '0', `is_decimal_divided` = '0' WHERE (item_id='X')
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-5 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty+1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-3 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-10 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `product_id` = 'X', `stock_id` = '1', `qty` = '9993', `min_qty` = '0', `use_config_min_qty` = '1', `is_qty_decimal` = '0', `backorders` = '0', `use_config_backorders` = '1', `min_sale_qty` = '1', `use_config_min_sale_qty` = '1', `max_sale_qty` = '10', `use_config_max_sale_qty` = '0', `is_in_stock` = '1', `low_stock_date` = 'XXXX-XX-XX 08:05:29', `notify_stock_qty` = NULL, `use_config_notify_stock_qty` = '1', `manage_stock` = '0', `use_config_manage_stock` = '1', `stock_status_changed_auto` = '0', `use_config_qty_increments` = '1', `qty_increments` = '0', `use_config_enable_qty_inc` = '1', `enable_qty_increments` = '0', `is_decimal_divided` = '0' WHERE (item_id='X')
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty+3 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-5 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty+1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `product_id` = 'X', `stock_id` = '1', `qty` = '9980', `min_qty` = '0', `use_config_min_qty` = '1', `is_qty_decimal` = '0', `backorders` = '0', `use_config_backorders` = '1', `min_sale_qty` = '1', `use_config_min_sale_qty` = '1', `max_sale_qty` = '10', `use_config_max_sale_qty` = '0', `is_in_stock` = '1', `low_stock_date` = 'XXXX-XX-XX 08:05:48', `notify_stock_qty` = NULL, `use_config_notify_stock_qty` = '1', `manage_stock` = '0', `use_config_manage_stock` = '1', `stock_status_changed_auto` = '0', `use_config_qty_increments` = '1', `qty_increments` = '0', `use_config_enable_qty_inc` = '1', `enable_qty_increments` = '0', `is_decimal_divided` = '0' WHERE (item_id='X')
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-10 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-10 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN X THEN qty-1 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `qty` = CASE product_id WHEN Y THEN qty-1 WHEN X THEN qty-10 ELSE qty END WHERE (product_id IN (Y, X)) AND (stock_id = 1)
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET `product_id` = 'X', `stock_id` = '1', `qty` = '9979', `min_qty` = '0', `use_config_min_qty` = '1', `is_qty_decimal` = '0', `backorders` = '0', `use_config_backorders` = '1', `min_sale_qty` = '1', `use_config_min_sale_qty` = '1', `max_sale_qty` = '10', `use_config_max_sale_qty` = '0', `is_in_stock` = '1', `low_stock_date` = 'XXXX-XX-XX 08:06:26', `notify_stock_qty` = NULL, `use_config_notify_stock_qty` = '1', `manage_stock` = '0', `use_config_manage_stock` = '1', `stock_status_changed_auto` = '0', `use_config_qty_increments` = '1', `qty_increments` = '0', `use_config_enable_qty_inc` = '1', `enable_qty_increments` = '0', `is_decimal_divided` = '0' WHERE (item_id='X')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known `Magento bug`. No fix is available so far. The only solution for now is to set "`Notify for quantity below`" to 0.

For more info:
[Post on Magento forum](http://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Magento-1-9-0-1-misscalculates-inventory-when-under-heavy-load/m-p/4043#U4043)
bug reported here:
[Bug report (requires user account)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/743)